# trim char array C++

Tags: c++, trim

How do i trim a char array ?

I'm reading this array from the text file and when it matches a certain string , ive to process it. But it never matches. I assume because it contains some trailing and leading spaces or\and '\n'

I dont know how to trim a char array but i used this to removes spaces. This has a problem that when `token[0] = {0 0 0 0}` this makes it {0000}. So i dont know what to do next..

```
char a[50] = {0};
int j = 0;

    //Removing spaces or garbage values in token[0] for perfect string match
    for(int i=0; (unsigned)i<strlen(token[0]) ; ++i )
    {
      if( (isalnum(token[0][i])) || token[0][i] == 95)
      {
        a[j]=token[0][i];
        j++;
      }
      else
      {
        continue;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried?

Comment: .. So write some code to take care of those eventualities.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to do that !

Comment: @dharag - Why not post it and tell what is not working!

Comment: Where is the array `token` being populated from?

Comment: From a configuration text file. Each line in the text file is being tokenized using strtok

Comment: For a start you refer to `token[0]` and not `token[1]` throughout your code.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you have not mentioned anything else, the following could always be done:

copy the array(to be checked) to another array char by char to only the number of chars required...(this way you could also check how many chars you need to trim):

```
a=0;

while(array1[a] != '\0'){
    array2[a] = array1[a];
    a++;
}

array2[a] = '\0';
```